# How to make directive re-render view in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, scope, coffeescript

I would like to truncate text dynamically, on each data change and each window's resize event.

Lets's say I have a HTML:

```
<p ng-truncate='lines: 2'> Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
```

My directive does the truncation, but still it lacks of re-truncation on window's resize.

```
angular.module('moduleName', [])
  .directive 'ngTruncate', () ->
    link: (scope, element, attributes) ->
      // Direcive code here
      $(window).on 'resize', ->
        scope.$apply()
        scope.$digest()
```

Unfortunatelly, `$apply`, nor `$digest()` do not work.

Moreover, I believe I should use `$window` somehow...

Answer (score 1):

Probably nothing has changed in `$scope` before you called `$apply` or `$digest` on resize.

Better add some function, eg.:

```
function onWindowChange() {
    // do some changes to any 
    // attributes of scope
    // and than apply them
    scope.$digest()
}

// and call it on window resize
$window.resize(onWindowChange);
```

Or you may have function wich will change 
any scope attr, wich you call on many
different events, and `$scope.$watch` this attr
and on change call `$scope.$digest`.

Maybe it would be easier to answer if you posted whole directive code here...

Comment: Unfortunatelly changing any scope value on $(window).on 'resize' do not call automatically for $apply/$digest.

Comment: do both - call `$apply`/`$digest` in event callback after changing any scope value

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can use the `$window` property to keep a watch over the change to the size of the window.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fQgXQ/).

Original discussion can be found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/angular/ZDpzFxLZz1w) (from where the fiddle was picked)

Comment: I appreciate this answer, however I belive this directive should be invisible to controller, purely view-dedicated piece of code. Is this possible?

Comment: In the fiddle, you find that the `$watch` lies inside the controller - you can also move this code inside your directive - In the code that you have provided, inside the link function, you can have the `$watch` code. Is that what you mean by having a directive invisible to controller?