# Angular directive re-compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, smart-table

i am trying to re-render directive contents, i tried multiple solution i found but most of them freeze the browser or just doesnt work, this is my directive:

```
angular.module('app.common.directives')
.directive('stColumns', function ($compile, $window, $timeout) {

    return {
        require: '^stTable',
        compile: function(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
            var displayIdx = $window.innerWidth > 1000 ? 'display' : 'displaySm';
            tElement.find('tr').each(function(idx, el) {
                $(el).find('td, th').each(function(tdIdx, td) {
                    $(td).attr('ng-if', 'stColumnsStatus[' + tdIdx + '] && stColumnsStatus[' + tdIdx + '].' + displayIdx);
                });
            });

            return {
                post: function(scope, iElem, attr) {
                    scope.stColumnsStatus = scope[attr.stColumns];
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

simple smart-table plugin that adds column definiton, the think i wanna add is to re-render the whole table once the user is resizing the window so the 'displayIdx' variable will change to fit the window.

i am new to angular so i am also not sure i am doing it right :)

Comment: Hasn't this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057599/how-to-make-directive-re-render-view-in-angular worked for you?